# WebStorm DartUnit with test api, run/debug error

Tags: dart, dart-unittest

I'm using WebStorm IDE and [test](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test) api which is named [unittest](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/unittest) before. The test works fine using the command:

> pub run test:test test/sample.dart

**/test/sample.dart**

```
library testproject.sample;

import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test('Testing', () {
    expect(true, isTrue);
  });
}
```

but when i tried to run/debug using WebStorm DartUnit the test, the console shows this error:

```
Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: Load Error: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:\Users\dummy\Desktop\testproject\packages\unittest\unittest.dart' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
, errno = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

WebStorm is still hardwired to the old `unittest` package. There is an open issue to fix this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16053

You can however execute Dart test scripts using the new `test` package like any other Dart script, to be able to use the debugger. If you use custom HTML pages for your tests, you need to replace the `x-dart-test` link to a proper Dart script tag to be able to execute it from WebStorm.